# SQL Server 2014 unable to see C: drive when restoring a database

Tags: sql-server, backup, file-permissions

When I try to restore a database, I'm completely unable to see my see my C: drive in order to choose a back up file.

I can't see any files. No matter what path I put in. This worked before on another machine, and I've followed the same installation attempts on this one. Why can not see any files?

This is all that I see:

[image]

EDIT: Found the problem, I full screened the window and I can now see it. My GUI is messed up, you can see it at the top of the picture.

Comment: Looks to me like the file location box has a path on the c drive already. That indicates it can "see" it. Perhaps the folder in there doesn't exist or has no files in it? We can't really tell from here.

Comment: Is that happen only for C drive?

Comment: Seems like a bug or something related to your windows settings and less to do with SQL Server itself.

Comment: @SeanLange The file path is correct and their is a .bak file in their. And I only have a C drive.

Comment: Then it is most likely a windows permission issue.